# heroku run bash gives error: ! ! ETIMEDOUT: connect ETIMEDOUT 50.19.103.36:5000

Tags: windows-firewall, heroku-cli

I'm trying to use `heroku run bash` on windows 10.

I have tried allowing the port 5000 through the firewall and restarting Command Prompt as administrator.

Is there anything else I am missing to get a connection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Commands can be run from the [heroku dashboard](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1137)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your ISP or network (Wi-Fi) is blocking port 5000. If nothing else works, use a VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Heroku run commands** from Dashboard Instead of windows command prompt or git bash or other terminals.

I hope this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i got the same error too when i was trying to push into heroku.
only to find out that i had to first commit everything on git before trying to login or push into heroku.

so before you try to login. make sure that your working tree is empty!!!